# Matching a string with regex?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match, cpanel

I am looking to match several full strings in regex for a cpanel filter, but cannot seem to get it working.

I am wanting to match the string no matter where it is, even if its embedded or in strange casing like so.. embed**STriNg**embed

For instance this string: **To view this email as a web page, click here**

```
[Tt]o view this email as a web page, click here.*?
```

but this doesn't work.

I dont want to anchor it as it might not be at the beginning of a sentence, i just want to match it no matter where or how its written.

Thanks.

Comment: it's working https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/5

Comment: "or in strange casing like so.. embedSTriNgembed" - the problem i have is cpanel filters. When i use the above regex with /ig for case insensitive it doesnt work. is there any other way for case-insensitive?

Comment: put `(?i)` at the regex start

Comment: You are speaking of finding non case sensitive strings, yet your example is of finding a single character. Makes your question slightly confusing because it seems like you have posted a working solution. Can you post your actual regex so we can se what is going on with it?

Comment: Regardless, this works for a specific string `[SsTtRrIiNnGg]`

Comment: That was my actual solution, all i could do was match it exactly or all lower, hence the [Tt]o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the case insensitive modifier in two different ways.

1. `/regex/i` We could add the case insensitive or any other modifiers by adding the corresponding letter next to the regex delimiter. In some languages, we need to add this as a separate parameter like `re.IGNORECASE` in python etc.
2. We could also add the modifier on the regex itself by adding `(?i)` at the start of the regex. You could include more num of modifiers inside those brackets like `(?im)`